# Community with Napili template not showing Knowledge articles correctly or well

Tags: community, knowledge, napili

When we view the knowledge article in the napili themed community, they do not show well, sometimes the content is not displayed at all or when displayed, its garbled.

Comment: Can you be more specific with screenshot here ?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this might help you

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_community_workspaces_access.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.10

In the builder, you need to make publish the things